# How did < 1K User delete someone else's answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Came across this question:

> [Choose time using datetimepicker in propertygrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4460489/719186)

The OP posted the question in December 2010, then it looks like the OP edited the question an hour later to include an answer.  Six months later the OP posts the answer in the actual answer block and accepts it.

Three days later, another user (less than 1000 rep) copies the posted answer and edits it into the question and then deletes the accepted answer.

That doesn't seem appropriate, but how did that happen?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Dori Smith [used to be a community manager](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-valued-associate-dori-smith/).

As such she had moderator powers at the time.

Her [Careers 2.0 CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/dori) states she held the role from February 2011 until November 2011; the edits you found were smack in the middle of that time.

I'm not sure why she made the edit however; the *exact same text* was already in the question body, and it seems like the OP had used an answer post correctly here. Feel free to remove Dori's additional text, clean up the question formatting (it could use it) and flag the answer for undeletion.

Comment: **smack** right in the middle!

Comment: Shouldn't she have a hollow diamond then?  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech honestly, I've kind of wanted that as a new feature recently. It's weird to come across posts that have been closed by one person without a diamond (nor a dupe hammer), until you realize that the person *used* to be a moderator (or in this case, used to have moderator powers).

Comment: @Cupcake It [seems feasible](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/hollow-diamonds-for-former-mods).

Comment: @Cupcake I think the better approach is to display the privileges a user held at the time they took an action, not the privileges they have now. There are several related issues, like wondering why a diamond's vote was not binding (they weren't a diamond yet) or why a gold badge's duplicate vote wasn't binding.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that'd mean a lot of overhead to keep all that information stored for posterity. Probably not worth the storage space and query execution time for the relatively limited use it has to satisfy the odd inquisitive spirit.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: a gold-badge duplicate vote that isn't binding doesn't show up with a gold circle next to their name. That one is easy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters except for those closed between the roll out of the hammer and the implementation of the gold-badge indicator :) (eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594162/why-default-parameter-doesnt-work-for-python-object-distinguish)

Comment: @.MartijnPieters Then we should use the same mechanism for diamond votes @jwenting We're talking about one bit per vote here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: perhaps; I got the impression that the 'close' banner is baked now (recording the gold badge if it was a dupe hammer close), so perhaps this is already the case.

Comment: Martijn, employees even without the diamond can have moderator-like abilities, and [this answer is being used as source to claim that moderators can somehow change the accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322645/an-answer-of-mine-was-accepted-what-happens-if-i-modify-it?lq=1#comment342050_322661).

Comment: @Braiam: which is an entirely misguided notion as no-one marked an answer as accepted here. All Dori did was *delete* the post. I don't care if Dori actually had a diamond next to her name at the time, she probably did. I am sticking to the wording 'moderator abilities' here because moderators have the same abilities Dori used here, e.g. we can delete an answer marked accepted. The accept vote doesn't go away when we do this, as evidenced by the fact that undeleting the OP answer re-instated the accept mark.