# Edit accepted answer for brevity

Tags: discussion

I am new to answering questions on SO. As a former instructor, my answers can be "thorough". In one case, my answer has been accepted but it did not give the OP exactly what he wanted because what he wanted was impractical. But I gave him some good examples and he was happy. Subsequently I was able to come up with several permutations that got closer to what he was looking for. So now the answer has several updates that evolve toward a recommended solution. It feels pretty long and I thought about editing it to consolidate or eliminate some of the examples. As an accepted answer, though, I am not sure how much I should actually remove. The examples do follow a path that leads up to a much better answer. I am inclined to leave it. But I would like to know if there is a rule-of-thumb about the author editing his/her own answer when it has already been accepted.

For reference, the question is [Removing taken numbers from a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647112/removing-taken-numbers-from-a-list/38647768#38647768).

Comment: The one tip i can give you there: Try not to write "UPDATE" when updating like that.... your edits should make it look like your answer had been that way all along. Also.... looking at the question, I have a feeling it SHOULD be a duplicate...

Comment: For a [related question I answered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322661/6083675), my conclusion is that either way is fine. You might be able to restructure the answer so the most relevant part is at the top, and use the phrase "if you want to do <whatever>, then..." That's what I do (although it's not as long usually.) In any case, it's high quality and you should worry less :)

Comment: Yes, reading Laurel's comment I realized I didn't say that your answer was actually a really good one :). Apologies for that :P. Keep the high quality content up!

Comment: I like the idea of moving the most relevant answer to the top. Also, I thought using UPDATE was a kind of protocol to let the OP know that something was added or changed. But it really does look cluttered. What I am getting from these answers is that an edit would be OK as long as the content that satisfied the OP is still there.

Comment: @rhaben yes, 100%! A lot of people do use "UPDATE" or "EDIT" but, at the end of the day, your post should look as if it always had that content. Just make sure the answer is still answering the OP's question, you're golden :)

Comment: I implemented your suggestions. Please feel free to take a look. I am very happy at how it came out. Because it was my first accepted answer, I spent a lot of time on it. But I think I have the hang of it now. Thanks!!!